# i got rmdir error for react app when i install react app

Tags: reactjs

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\7944\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules'
    at Object.rmdirSync (fs.js:769:3)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:364:25)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:342:7)
    at rimrafSync (C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:312:9)
    at C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:350:5
    at Array.forEach ()
    at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:349:26)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:342:7)
    at rimrafSync (C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:312:9)
    at C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:350:5 {
  errno: -4051,
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
  path: 'C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\7944\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules'
}

Comment: Might be a someother process is holding the resource. Try to identify other possible process that could be holding it and kill them. Or simply restart your machine and check if it happens again.

Comment: I am trying this but it's not working  and, I want react js using a class but when I try create-react-app and it gives in function type how can I switch to class-based